# Gstreamer unable to create new pipeline

Tags: c, c++11, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

So I am building a linux based c app using gstreamer. I have written the code for that and everything works fine for the first run.(As the source code consists of multiple files, I would not prefer to paste it here).

I am using a Glib main loop and am attaching a signal to the bus and am if an error is enocountered, I do the cleaning.

The issue is, after doing the cleaning when I try to recall my main function again, gstreamer fails to create a new pipeline i.e `gst_pipeline_new` creates/returns an empty pipeline.

I just wish to know about the possible scenarios when this sort of behaviour happens i.e. what makes `gst_pipeline_new` fail ? I am not looking for a direct solution to my problem but any pointers as to when `gst_pipeline_new` fails ?

Comment: without creation and clean up code all it possible to tell that some node actually may cause it, it might be a bug. segfaults on recreation removed pipelines was a thing for some buggy drivers, e.g. nvidia

Comment: Define `GST_DEBUG=3` environment variable before run your application and you will see what's the problem in console.